# How to render a Handlebars partial multiple times with different data each time and one next to each other?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to render a hbs partial multiple times but each time with different data and one next to each other. Here's an example code:

This is the main js file where I request data to a MongoDB database, productDB is the main object with all the products:

```
        for (const p in productDB) {

        // Helper that I use in the partial
        hbs.registerHelper('getTitle', () => {
        // This should show different titles like product1, product2, product3
            return productDB[p].productTitle;

        });
```

then in the partial.hbs I have this:

```
<h5>{{getTitle}}</h5>
```

and lastly, in the main hbs file where I use the partial, I have this code, where "product" is a list with each product title:

```
{{#each product}}
   {{> partial}}
{{/each}}
```

What's the result I actually have? Multiple < h5 > tags with the same title from the first product.

What I expect? I want multiple < h5 > tags next to each other with different text each one.

I hope I have explained well what I want, thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not make sense to call `registerHelper` within a loop. You should register a helper with a given name only once. I don't understand why you need this helper. Doesn't each `product` object know its own title?

Comment: You are right. The helper was the first thing that came to my mind to send data to the partial. The product object that I use to repeat the partial is an array with 4 products titles. So there's another way of sending data to a partial instead of using a helper?

Comment: You can pass contexts to Partials. For the docs, see: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-contexts; for an example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/erdf42a5/

Comment: Thanks you so much! that solved my problem :)